# SELECT из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Не знаю, как сформулировать правильно, возможно ли выполнить две выборки в одном SQL запросе?
Есть веб-интерфейс для отслеживания работы сотрудников. Есть диапазон номеров, из которого и будет браться информация. Требуется брать этот диапазон номеров из другой таблицы, которая будет привязана ко второму интерфейсу, способному этот диапазон изменять "руками".
Мой вариант:

```
Select
  DATE_FORMAT(datetime,  '%H') as DATE,
  COUNT(1) as COUNT,
  ROUND((sum(Billable))/COUNT(1)) as TIME FROM `slave`.`cdr_201602`
Where datetime > CURDATE()
  and HOUR(datetime) > 8
  and HOUR(datetime) < 18
  and (src between 501 and 565 or src=129 or src=444) and billable >1
  GROUP BY date order by date
```

Мне требуется брать значения src не из этой же таблицы, а из другой. 
Что то вроде `Select * from table_1, and select src from table_2;`

Comment: вы бы пример данных и желаемый результат еще бы привели, вообще на `join` похоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно ли я понимаю, что речь идет об этой строке?

```
(src between 501 and 565 or src=129 or src=444)
```

Вы можете воспользоваться вложенными запросами, т.е. поместить запрос к другой строке в скобки и запросить вхождение при помощи оператора IN

```
src IN (SELECT id FROM table_2 WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Перечисляешь все таблицы через запятую после FROM. А к полям обращаешься через точку после имени таблицы, пример ниже:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
    ,table2
WHERE table1.username = table2.username
AND table1.username = 'user'
```